# ansible gather facts undefined variable

Tags: ansible

I'm trying to display some variables about the hosts using ansible gather facts.
Here's the yml file

```
- name: setup users
  gather_facts: true
  hosts: hosts
  tasks:
    name: display stats after login
    template: 
      src: /stats.j2
      dest: /etc/motd
    become: true
```

Here's the jinja2 file

```
Arch: {{ hostvars[inventory_hostname]['ansible_architecture'] }}
```

Accoring to anisble -m setup the variable exits but I'm always getting an error that the variable is undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would use `{{hostvars['inventory_hostname']['...']}}`.
But if you do not want to access informations from other hosts you could change your template (stats.j2) to

```
Arch: {{ansible_architecture}}
```

Comment: I tried both versions and still get the same error that the variable is undefined.

Comment: It actually works now don't really know what the problem was but thanks.